# Jmeter gives incorrect Date when we use TimeShift function

Tags: jmeter

I need to pass a future date i.e. current+1 in format yyyy-mm-dd but when I am trying the function : ${__timeShift(yyyy-mm-dd,,P1D,,)} then I am getting below response : 2023-29-27.
Current date is 2023-07-26 and so the expected date should be 2023-07-27

What could be the reason and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter gives "correct" date, it just doesn't match your expectation

I think you need to use capital `M` because `m` stands for `minute-of-hour` and `M` is for `month-of-year`

[image]

More information:

- [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timeshift-function)